# How to add a regex pattern for decimal places in an input tag?

Tags: regex, html

I'm trying to autoformat an input tag to display decimal places.. I first thought that maybe I should use Javascript but after some research I discovered that it could be done using html5 specifically using the **pattern** attribute. I was told that you can assign a regex expression in it but I could not find any.

this is my input tag

```
<input type='text' name='amount' id='amount'/>
```

Comment: The pattern attribute only allows for certain patterns to be submitted, it does not auto format the input tag.

Comment: Stick with the javascript method as not all browsers support all of the  new html5 input types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the 'number' type

```
    <style>
       input:valid +p { display:none }
       input:invalid +p { display:block }
    </style>

   <form>
      <input type="number"  min="0.5" max="3.14" step="0.01" required ></input>
      <p>Must be provided and be a decimal.</p>
   </form>
```